# The item exists in the array but it says that the array is 0 length?

Tags: javascript

I can add an item to an array it and I can access that item, but the `length` reports `0`. Why?

```
var arr = [];
arr[4294967300] = "My item";
console.log(arr[4294967300], arr.length); // Outputs "My item", 0
```

Comment: I think JavaScript is being stretched to limit. Oh JavaScript!

Comment: well this kind of index would stretch any programming language

Comment: just over the limit.. coincidence? Maybe not ;)

Comment: if you would like to get the "length" of that object see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array

Comment: Actually in this example using that code would return `1`, but if I was expecting it to act like an array I would expect to see a length of `4294967301`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the index is so big that it gets turned into a property instead, hence the length is 0.

According to the [ECMAScript documentation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.4), a particular value p can only be an array index if and only if:

```
(p >>> 0 === p) && (p >>> 0 !== Math.pow(2, 32) - 1)
```

Where `>>> 0` is equivalent to `ToUint32()`. In your case:

```
4294967300 >>> 0 // 4
```

By definition, the `length` property is always one more than the numeric value of the biggest valid index; negative indices would give you the same behaviour, e.g.

```
arr[-1] = 'hello world';
arr.length; // 0
arr['-1']; // 'hello world'
```

If your numbers range between what's valid (and gets used as an index) and "invalid" (where it gets turned into a property), it would be better to cast all your indices to a string and work with properties all the way (start with `{}` instead of `Array`).

Comment: Honest question, is there any reason you used a zero-fill bit shift over the other shifts or a bitwise or `p | 0`?

Comment: @StuartWakefield it's a special shr operation in the sense that it also casts to an unsigned 32 bit integer, hence the triple bracket for extra kick :)

Comment: Don't all bitwise operators cast operands to 32 bit integers?

Comment: @StuartWakefield Yes, all bit wise operators cast to int32, but >>> clears the sign bit as well, turning it into uint32

Comment: Nice one, that answers it perfectly `-1 | 0` gives `-1` but `-1 >>> 0` gives `4294967295`. Cheers for finding that out for me